# WSO2 API Manager 1.6.0 - API Authentication Failure

Tags: security, wso2, config

-Updated with pics of request header and params.

Can anyone tell me why WSo2 API Manager does not authenticate?
I have set up two WSo2 API Manager 1.6.0 instances.  One that is distributed and a stand alone instance.  I also have created a version of the CDYNE sample API that requires authorization and another version that does not.  It does not appear that the API is published correctly because it does not matter what level I set the api security to when creating the api.
Here is the api on the gateway:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Creator1--APIPhoneVerify" context="/APIPhoneVerify" version="2.0.0" version-type="url">
    <resource methods="POST GET OPTIONS DELETE PUT" url-mapping="/CheckPhoneNumber">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
            <filter source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE" regex="PRODUCTION">
                <then>
                    <send>
                        <endpoint name="Creator1--APIPhoneVerify_APIproductionEndpoint_0">
                            <http uri-template="http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx">
                                <timeout>
                                    <duration>30000</duration>
                                    <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                                </timeout>
                                <suspendOnFailure>
                                    <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
                                    <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
                                    <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                                    <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                                </suspendOnFailure>
                                <markForSuspension>
                                    <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
                                </markForSuspension>
                            </http>
                        </endpoint>
                    </send>
                </then>
                <else>
                    <send>
                        <endpoint name="Creator1--APIPhoneVerify_APIsandboxEndpoint_0">
                            <http uri-template="http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx">
                                <timeout>
                                    <duration>30000</duration>
                                    <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                                </timeout>
                                <suspendOnFailure>
                                    <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
                                    <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
                                    <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                                    <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                                </suspendOnFailure>
                                <markForSuspension>
                                    <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
                                </markForSuspension>
                            </http>
                        </endpoint>
                    </send>
                </else>
            </filter>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
    <handlers>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler"/>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler">
            <property name="id" value="A"/>
            <property name="policyKey" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml"/>
        </handler>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler"/>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtGoogleAnalyticsTrackingHandler"/>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler"/>
    </handlers>
</api>
```

When I use the 'try it' feature it appears that the key is not passed and I get an error.
Here is the key:
[image]

Here is the response:
[image]

Here is the wso2carbon.log:

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-02-05 14:25:02,513] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} -  API authentication failure {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Access failure for API: /APIPhoneVerify, version: 2.0.0 with key: null
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:139)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:285)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:63)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:336)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:168)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-02-05 14:25:02,516]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bam.message.tracer.handler.util.HandlerUtils} -  Massage Info: Transaction id=115815524651347724395990  Message direction=OUT  Server name=7.40.2.26:9765  Timestamp=1391631902516  Service name=__SynapseService  Operation Name=mediate {org.wso2.carbon.bam.message.tracer.handler.util.HandlerUtils}
```

I then tried from an external source in case it was a 'tryit' problem.  In this case the key was at least passed.
Here is the request and reply:
[image]

Here is the wso2carbon.log:

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-02-05 14:26:24,053] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} -  API authentication failure {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Access failure for API: /APIPhoneVerify, version: 2.0.0 with key: CgtcOiDinAKo4hKbtDV_fr6JIVAa
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:139)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:285)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:63)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:336)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:168)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-02-05 14:26:24,056]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bam.message.tracer.handler.util.HandlerUtils} -  Massage Info: Transaction id=115823714657361932967093  Message direction=OUT  Server name=7.40.2.26:9765  Timestamp=1391631984056  Service name=__SynapseService  Operation Name=mediate {org.wso2.carbon.bam.message.tracer.handler.util.HandlerUtils}
```

Comment: Hi can you also provide with details of the API invocation, what parameters you are using to make the invocations as well as the header

Comment: @Nadeesha  Thanks for the help, I'll post those in an answer so I can add pictures.  I hope this can get resovled soon as we are close to just cutting over to Layer7 instead.

Comment: @Nadeesha I updated the original question...

Comment: hi @Gammonster please note that the key expires after a given validity period, please refresh the key and try it with the internal REST client provided, Make sure that the API is subscribed to the given application to which the key is issued. This shouldnt be a problem at all is it is a straight forward scenario.

Comment: @Nadeesha The key was already set to expire at 3600 seconds (60 minutes).  Both attempts were done within 10 minutes of obtaining the key.  I just tried again, and had the same results.  Is there some logging that might illuminate the issue?  The response to using the included rest client was: <ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security"><ams:code>900906</ams:code><ams:message>No matching resource found in the API for the given request</ams:message><ams:description>Access failure for API: /APIPhoneVerify, version: 2.0.0 with key: null</ams:description></ams:fault>

Comment: Can you please try this API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this API

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather
```

with parameter `q=London`

The final request should look like the following

```
http://localhost:8280/yourAPI/1.0?q=London
```

Comment: I added that one...and it was blocked.  Which is good, because it means that at least a call was attempted.  So this led me to look at the Phone verify sample.  I had defined it with a URL pattern of /CheckPhoneNumber  which did not work.  Your suggestion led me to believe my get commands couldn't find the matching resource url.  So I published again with /* as the url pattern, went and edited the swagger api in the doc section to add /CheckPhoneNumber and that version (1.6.1) works.  I'll post in the answer...but they look the same?

Comment: What i would suggest is to do it fresh create a new API with /* resource URL and try whether it works for the checkPhoneNumber or else try the weather API which is more reliable and would help you to get ur API Manager running as expected

Comment: We had the same thought...I added in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have added 2 versions of the same api.  1.6.0 (which doesn't work) and 1.6.1 (which does work).
The error message regarding API authenication failure led me to believe it was a auth problem.
However, since your worked with the /* url pattern I tried that, instead of a pattern of /CheckPhoneNumber and it worked.  I guess having a url pattern of /CheckPhoneNumber and updating the swagger doc to have the definition include /CheckPhoneNumber are NOT the same thing.